# Proving that for all $x\in\mathbb R:\; -a < x < a$ if and only if $|x| < a$.

Tags: proof-writing, absolute-value

I'm in an intro to proof-writing class, studying for a final exam.
 I've been struggling with this problem for quite some time now and am able to prove it one way and not the other. I have so far completed the proof that if $|x| < a$, then $-a < x < a$. I wrote it as follows:

Suppose that $|x| < a$. Then, we have two cases.

For the first case, suppose that $x \geq 0$. Then by definition of absolute value, $x < a$. Because $x \geq 0$, it is the case that $a > 0$. Then $-a < 0$. Thus, $-a < x < a$ when $x > 0$.

Secondly, suppose that $x < 0$. Then by definition of absolute value, $-x < a$. This implies that $x > -a$. Then because $x < 0$, $-a < 0$. Thus $a > 0$. Therefore $-a < x < a$ when $x < 0$.

Thus, if $|x| < a$, then $-a < x < a$.

However, I cannot figure out the proof that if $-a < x < a$, then $|x| < a$. Any suggestions?

Comment: What *is* the definition of absolute value you use?

Comment: Hint:  When you say if $|x| < a$ then you have two cases: i) $x \ge 0$ or ii) $x < 0$.... you have the same two cases for *any* proposal.  If $-a < x < a$ you *still* have the same two cases: i) $x\ge 0$ or ii) $x < 0$.  So if $x\ge 0$ what happens?  And if $x < 0$ what happens?  Hint 2: if $x \ge 0$ then $x = |x|$ so $-a < |x| < a$.  If $x < 0$ then $x=-|x|$ so $-a < -|x| < a$.....

Comment: "For the first case, suppose that x≥0. Then by definition of absolute value, x<a. Because x≥0, it is the case that a>0. Then −a<0. Thus, −a<x<a when x>0."  Why is $x < a$?  We know that $|x| < a$ but why can't we have $|x| < a < x$?

Comment: I’ve never heard of a class that focusses on writing proofs; that’s really interesting.

Comment: Math 301, Intro to Proof Writing. The textbook is open source, here's a link: https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/textbooks/book-of-proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just definitions and reverse

If $-a < x < a$ then... well to begin with $a > 0$.... if $a = 0$ or $a < 0$ then $-a < a$ would be impossible...  so

If $-a < x < a$ then either $-a < x < 0$ or $0 \le x < a$.

If $-a < x < 0$ then $x < 0$ and $|x| = -x$ and $x = -|x|$ so $-a < -|x| < 0$ so $0 < |x| < a$.

And if $0 \le x < a$ then $x \ge 0$ and $|x| = x$ so $0 \le |x| < a$.

So either way $|x| < a$.

Comment: Ah thanks! I for some reason hadn't thought to use the definition of absolute value, but that makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

If $x>0 \Rightarrow   x=|x|$

$-a<x<a$ implies $-a<|x|<a$ which means $|x|<a$

If $x<0 \Rightarrow x=-|x|$ 
which implies $-a<-|x|$  which means $|x|<a$

I will leave $x=0$ for the reader to prove :)

P.S. I am using as definition of absolute value of $x$ 
$$\begin{cases} 
|x|=x,\ x>=0 \\
|x|=-x,\ x<0 \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Once again, I had forgotten to use the definition of absolute value! I'll try that and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Below an attempt for --> direction  with emphasis on the logical structure of the reasoning

[image]